# How to link React Components inside anchor tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have several components and routes in my app. I have a sidebar menu that has links to other components in my app. I tried adding the components but it does not ho anything, it renders a blank page. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help appreciated.

This is my Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import AddNewFileMT from './AddNewFileMT';
import Home from '../routes/Home';

const SideMenu = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <nav>
                <div>
                    <ul className="sidebar"> 
                        <br />  
                        <li>
                            <a href={<Home />}>Home<i className="fas fa-home"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href={<Archive />}>Archive<i className="fas fa-archive"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href={<AddNewFileMT />}>Add New<i className="fas fa-folder-open"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href={<Analytics />}>Analytics<i className="fas fa-chart-pie"></i></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>    
            </nav> 
        </div>
    );
};

export default SideMenu;
```

Then in my Route I have this:

```
import React from 'react'
import Header from '../components/Header'
import SideMenu from '../components/SideMenu'
import RegionalMap from '../components/RegionalMap'
import Footer from '../components/Footer'

export const Home = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Header />
            <SideMenu />
            <RegionalMap/>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    )
};

export default Home;
```

This is the address in the browser when a sidemenu item is clicked:
**http://localhost:3001/[object%20Object]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install [react-router-dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom)

import Router and Route then wrap your pages between a `<Router>` tag. Like this:

```
<Router>
  <Route component={componentHere} />
  ...
</Router>
```

then import Link in your navigation bar wrap your links with `<Link>` then add attribute `<Link to={/yourComponentName} />`

Hint: add exact attribute to your homepage otherwise all URL will redirect to "/" which is your homepage.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As [React documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link), you can use Link element instead anchor tag. For example:

```html
    <Link to="/about">About</Link>
```

Take a look at the official documentation about Link elements

In your case, you can use

```html
    <Link to={ ROUTES.HOME } key='Home'>Home</Link>
```